# How to deal with the scrollbar inside a fixed element (top: 100px) that triggers 100px later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed element that needs to stay 100px from top and 0px from the right side and I want a scrollbar inside it. I deal with this by having an absolute positioned element inside on which I apply `overflow: scroll`. This works fine BUT it looks like **the scrollbar appears 100px (exactly the top px value) later than it should**. So 100px of content is hidden.

If I remove the `top:100px` property, the scrollbar appears exactly when it should.

If needed, this is my HTML:

```
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="absolute">
        {content}
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
.absolute{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Is there any solution to overcome this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: How about setting width and height of the positioned fixed element?

Comment: @Jai edited the code. I set the width, but it has nothing to do with the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @SujataChanda I provided the code.

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/856xhe3n/. I am not sure whether I have got what you wanted but if you need anything else please let me know.

Comment: In that fiddle the scroll bar appears at the top of `.absolute` as expected. What is the issue? Maybe a screenshot of what you are seeing would be useful